# Better coding practice: loop using dplyr to produce summary stats

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, statistics

I have 2 variables that I want to summarise and I'm struggling to loop in R. I want to group the variable by year then summarize both variables: `R_D$` and `Returns$`. My code is below... How would I do a loop instead of writing the code twice?

### Summary by select for R_D

```
 R_DYear<- df %>% group_by(Year) %>%
   do(data.frame(as.list(summary(.$`R_D$`)), check.names = FALSE))

 ds2 <-df %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   summarise( sum=sum(`R_D$`), sd=sd(`R_D$`))  
 R_DYear<- R_DYear%>% left_join(ds2)
```

### Summary by select for Returns

```
 Returs_Year<- df %>% group_by(Year) %>%
 do(data.frame(as.list(summary(.$`Returns$`)), check.names = FALSE))

 ds3 <-df %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   summarise( sum=sum(`Returns$`), sd=sd(`Returns$`))  
 Returs_Year<- Returs_Year %>% left_join(ds3)
```

### Below is a small example of the output for RD_Year

```
 Year   Min.    1st Qu. Median  Mean    3rd Qu. Max.    sum      sd
 2006     0      0.0    1.2     15.5    16.0    161.0   730.2   31.6
 2007     0      0.0    0.9     20.8    18.1    213.9   976.2   45.0
 2008     0      0.0    2.2     30.2    20.1    361.4   1418.6  72.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
df = data.frame(year = 1:4, replicate(2,sample(0:20,20,rep=TRUE)))
col = c("R_D","Returns" )
colnames(df)[2:3] <- col
```

Here is a method using aggregate

summary for R_D by year

```
aggregate(df[, c("R_D")] , df["year"], FUN = function(x) c(summary(x), sum = sum(x), sd = sd(x)))
```

summary for Returns by year

```
aggregate(df[, c("Returns")] , df["year"], FUN = function(x) c(summary(x), sum = sum(x), sd = sd(x)))
```

Edit1

```
df1 = aggregate(x= df[, c("R_D","Returns")] , df["year"], FUN = function(x) c(summary(x), sum = sum(x), sd = sd(x)))
R_D = as.data.frame(cbind(Year = df1$year, df1$R_D))
Returns = as.data.frame(cbind(Year = df1$year, df1$Returns))
```

Comment: ,Could you implement the code to output straight into a data frame?